# Build project in NetBeans

Tags: java

> build-impl.xml:929: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   build-impl.xml:269: Error running C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\javac.exe compiler

I add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin` to my `%PATH%` but the same. problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do the following ,it may help you.

1. Click On Libraries down below your project
2. Click On Properties
3. Checked Red Color Jar File List
4. Click ON Remove button
5. Exit NetBeans and restart it
6. Open and build

Comment: I did not find any  Red Color Jar File List.